# How to Modify Taxonomy Archive Page with Search Parameter?

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, pre-get-posts

I have Taxonomy called topic.

If user land this archive page like `example.com/topics/wordpress/` I need to out all posts which has `wordpress` word in title or description.

I added following code to do it.

```
function pp_change_page_layout( $query ) {


    if ( $query->is_main_query()) {        
        if ( is_tax('topics') ){
            $query->set('s' , 'WordPress'); // I hard code the search turm just for the testing purposes. I will take the archive slug.
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'pp_change_page_layout' );
```

But this is not work as I want. What this code done is, first it takes **all posts in topic Taxonomy** and then filter.

I want modify this code like below.

When user land `example.com/topics/wordpress/`, I **need to get all posts** (Not only in that Taxonomy) in my blog and then filter for `WordPress` word. How to modify above code to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution below will return posts associated with the queried term name **or** posts that use the term name in the post title, excerpt, or content.

Note that we are using the human readable term name for the search, not the term slug, which isn't ideal for searches since it could be hyphenated.

First, add the taxonomy term's name to the search query and wire up the filter to alter the search SQL:

```
/**
 * Adds taxonomy term name to search query and wires up posts_search
 * filter to change the search SQL.
 * 
 * @param WP_Query $query The WP_Query instance (passed by reference).
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_add_term_search_to_term_archive' );
function wpse_add_term_search_to_term_archive( $query ) {

    // Bail if this is the admin area or not the main query.
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }

    // Set the taxonomy associated with our term. Customize as needed.
    $taxonomy_slug = 'genre';

    // Get the term being used.
    $term_slug = get_query_var( $taxonomy_slug );

    if ( is_tax( $taxonomy_slug ) && $term_slug ) {
        // We have the term slug, but we need the human readable name. This
        // will be available in the term object.
        $term_object = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy_slug );

        // Bail if we can't get the term object.
        if ( ! $term_object ) {
            return;
        }

        // Sets this query as a search and uses the current term for our search.
        $query->set( 's' , $term_object->name );

        // Wire up a filter that will alter the search SQL so that the term archive
        // will include search results matching the term name *OR* posts assigned to
        // the term being queried.
        add_filter( 'posts_search', 'wpse_tax_term_posts_search', 10, 2 );
    }
}
```

Then, modify the search SQL so that results in **either** the tax query **or** the search query will be returned:

```
/**
 * Change the search SQL so that results in the tax query OR
 * the search query will be returned.
 *
 * @param string   $search Search SQL for WHERE clause.
 * @param WP_Query $wp_query   The current WP_Query object.
 */
function wpse_tax_term_posts_search( $search, $wp_query ) {
    // Replaces the first occurrence of " AND" with " OR" so that results in the 
    // tax query OR the search query will be returned.
    return preg_replace( '/^\s(AND)/', ' OR', $search );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check this answer in this weekend and then I will accept the answer. Again really thanks for the answer. I will check this on this weekend because I in outside the home town.

Comment: Wow. This is work. Thanks you so much. But you have done a small mistake in your code. If you can correct it, It will be helpful for feature readers. Otherwise they may think that you code it not working. You have called the `add_filter( 'posts_search', 'wpse_tax_term_posts_search', 10, 2 );` , but function name you have create `wpse_posts_search_add_term_search_to_term_archive`. It should be `wpse_tax_term_posts_search`. Thanks :-)

Comment: Ah, good catch @Ranuka! My naming conventions were getting a bit unwieldy and I intended to correct this with my posted answer but didn't update everything. Great question btw!

Comment: Thanks. :-) As I said this is working totally as I expected. But some codes I can't understand even you have commented really well. `add_filter( 'posts_search', 'wpse_tax_term_posts_search', 10, 2 );` means we call search function? Am I correct? But when you passed the tax slug in to that search function? And what `remove_filter( 'posts_search', 'wpse_tax_term_posts_search', 10, 2 );` code do? Yes, I saw your comment. But I am not got them meaning of "We only want the search filter to fire once, so unhook it".

Comment: After taking a closer look (and doing more testing), I've realized that the `remove_filter( 'posts_search', 'wpse_tax_term_posts_search', 10, 2 );` line is not needed. The code has been updated accordingly. I've also tried to explain why we need `add_filter( 'posts_search', 'wpse_tax_term_posts_search', 10, 2 );` a little better. Altering the search SQL is a key part of the solution since without it, the SQL would be looking for posts assigned to the term *which also contain the term name* in the post title, excerpt, or content.

Comment: Hi, As I already said this works perfectly fine. And I have another question and I know that it is separate question. So I will ask it as separate question if at least it is possible to answer. I need to display the post counter in-front of each each custom taxonomy in front end. I mean when we use `get_taxonomies()`. Or at least in Admin panel .. I prefer if it it can display the count in front end... But I don't know about performance and possibility. If you think it is possible please let me know. I will ask it as a separate question.

Comment: Hi @Ranuka, I do think it's possible and I think you're right that performance is an important consideration here. After doing a quick scan, it seems that you could use the [`$update_count_callback`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/dd330359eb5389246605c913622d703613520855/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L361) argument to define a callback that handles the term counting. Unfortunately, I don't have time to work out a tested solution this time.